# Read text in particular section of text and return remaining rows as key value pair

Tags: c#

I have a file that has a list of customer codes as below

```
[NationalCode]
NAT1=IRE
NAT2=LON
NAT3=DUB    
[customercodes]
 code1=Emer
 code2=John
 code3=Patrick
 code4=Sarah
```

I want to read the values in the customercodes section and put them into a dictionary as key value pairs. I have done the following but it keeps giving me an error. I need to only loop through the rows after the customercodes section

```
 public Dictionary<string, string> ParseSect(string Data)
    {
        string ini = File.ReadAllText(Data);
        var lines = ini.Split(new[] {'\r', '\n'}, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries);
        var dict = new Dictionary<string, string>();
        var rows = lines.Where(t => !String.IsNullOrEmpty(t.Trim()) && !t.StartsWith(";") && (t.Contains('[') || t.Contains('=')));

        if (rows == null || rows.Count() == 0) return dict;

        string section = "";
        foreach (string row in rows)
        {
            if (row == "[customercodes]")
            {
                section = "customercodes";
                string rw = row.TrimStart();
                int index = rw.IndexOf('=');
                dict[rw.Substring(0, index).Trim()] = rw.Substring(index + 1).Trim().Trim('"'); //Here is where I am getting an error
            }
        }

        return dict;
    }
```

Is there an easier way to do this? would appreciate some guidance on this. I am a newbie to this so forgive me if it is being overdone

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this

```
var codes = s.Substring(s.IndexOf("[customercodes]") + "[customercodes]".Length);
var pairs = codes.Split(new[] { '\r', '\n'}, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries);
var dictionary = pairs.Select(x => x.Split('=')).ToDictionary(x => x[0], x => x[1]);
```

It's short and readable.

The first line gets you to the part where the codes begin, then you split it by lines, and then by key/value.

Answer (score 0):

So in your particular example you actually process the header row as if it was a customer code - you look for the delimiter `=` and fail to find it and this causes your error. My advice here would be to break out some of your parsing into smaller expressions so they are easier to follow, read and debug:

```
string name = rw.Substring(0, index).Trim();
string code = rw.Substring(index + 1).Trim().Trim('"');
dict[name] = code;
```

As to another approach, here is a quick LINQ example (although kind of going against my prior advice to keep it readable!):

```
var lines = s.Split('\n').ToList();

var dict = lines.Skip(lines.FindIndex(l => l.StartsWith("[customercodes]")) + 1)
    .ToDictionary(k => k.Substring(k.IndexOf('=') + 1).Trim(), 
        v => v.Substring(0, v.IndexOf('=')).Trim());
```

Split the string by all new lines into a list. Then use the list find index to find the customer codes header and skip it then convert all subsequent lines to a name/code dictionary.